# Creating a new docker image with gradle 2.3

Tags: docker, gradle

I need to create a new docker image to use gradle version 2.3. There is no image that is publicly available for use and hence need to customize one. I'm not clear on what values should be given in Dockerfile for this version. My project has multiple project folders, which when built using gradle generates multiple gpars. Can someone please guide?

Answer (score 0):

you can use an alpine base image after that you can install gradle and start using it.

```sh
FROM alpine:3.10

ENV GRADLE_VERSION 3.2

RUN apk --no-cache add openjdk11 --repository=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community
RUN apk add bash vim curl wget jq docker git tar unzip bash-completion ca-certificates
RUN cd /opt && curl -sSl http://mirror.vorboss.net/apache/maven/maven-3/3.6.3/binaries/apache-maven-3.6.3-bin.tar.gz | tar -xz

RUN apk -U add --no-cache curl; \
    curl https://downloads.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-${GRADLE_VERSION}-bin.zip > gradle.zip; \
    unzip gradle.zip; \
    rm gradle.zip; \
    apk del curl; \
    apk update && apk add --no-cache libstdc++ && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

ENV PATH "$PATH:/opt/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin:/gradle-${GRADLE_VERSION}/bin/"
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]
```

This can help you to resolve your issue.

Comment: (Do you need `vim`, `docker`, or `jq` just to run Gradle?  Will that `ENTRYPOINT` work if the `CMD` is something like a JVM and not a shell script?)

Comment: yes of course entry point will execute an executable , example CMD ["/usr/bin/java", "-jar", "-Dspring.profiles.active=default", "/app.war"]